# How to improve my Mechincs skill is State of Decay 2

Tags: state-of-decay-2

I have been playing with a community member who has a Mechanics skill, but it does not seem to be improving.

Does anyone have any idea how to improve this skill?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mechanic skill is improved by actions at a workshop. If you look at the available actions in your workshop you will see in the description "improves xxx skill"

These skills will variate depending on the action. I believe scrapping a pile of broken weapons into parts will improve the mechanic skills (as one of many)